# Joining ESXi4 VMs to a DC when the DC is a HyperV VM

Tags: active-directory, vmware-esxi

I have two physical servers. One of these has HyperV running, and I have made one VM which is a domain controller (has AD/DNS and static IP). The host of this machine, a physical server, is in no way joined to the DC, it's just containing the VM.

However, there is a second physical server and ESXi 4 has been installed on this. I gave the guy who did this some details on AD (IP, FQDN, etc) and he did his stuff, saying that the host is part of that domain now.

Question is, if I make a guest VM in ESXi, can I go to DC and join this VM? I know this works because I have done this by adding VMs on a HyperV server to a standalone physical DC before, but I have never done this when the DC is an (always running) VM, and when the VMs are on ESXi (another physical box, though looking at the domain). Would this work?

In case you're wondering about this setup, I was keen on putting DC on physical and not doing with HyperV, but this is for a special product which requires a lot of infrastructure (virtualisation product) and there are all sorts of licensing issues which effect the infrastructure design decisions. This is for training/practise, not production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't make a difference what virtualization technology is used, this should work fine.